# Android notification not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-notifications

I've been attempting to get a notification of a successful upload from an ASyncTask to work all day.  I'm not getting any errors from my current code but I can't get the notification to show in the notification bar (or anywhere else).  I get no messages in LogCat and no notification appears in the Notification bar.  This is my code:

```
Notification mNotification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

CharSequence contentTitle = "upload completed.";
CharSequence contentText = "upload completed.";

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CastrActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
mNotification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

This is called from the onPostExecute() method of an ASyncTask.  I'm a bit confused on the PendingIntent part, to be honest.  Any clarification of what I suspect to be incorrect code there would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created the class to show notifications:

```
public class NotificationData {

    public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    public static int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;
    private Context _context;

    public NotificationData(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void clearNotification() {
        mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
    }

    public void SetNotification(int drawable, String msg, String action_string, Class cls) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(drawable, "Post Timer", System.currentTimeMillis());
        long[] vibrate = { 100, 100, 200, 300 };
        notifyDetails.vibrate = vibrate;
        notifyDetails.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
        notifyDetails.ledOnMS = 300;
        notifyDetails.ledOffMS = 1000;
     // notifyDetails.number=4;
        notifyDetails.defaults =Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        Context context = _context;
        CharSequence contentTitle = msg;
        CharSequence contentText = action_string;      
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,  cls);
     // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     // bundle.putBoolean(AppConfig.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        notifyIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(_context, 0,notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);        
    }
}
```

How to use this class:

```
NotificationData notification; //create object
notification = new NotificationData(this);
notification.SetNotification(R.drawable.notification, "Notification Title", "Click to open", YourClassName.class);
```

Add permission `android.permission.VIBRATE`

Comment: I'm sorry but what is AppConfig?  Is there a library I need to include to use that?  Eclipse doesn't seem to know it if there is so I'd have to add it to my build path.

Comment: Appconfig is a class and the IS_NOTIFICATION is a static member you can delete this line  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
      bundle.putBoolean(AppConfig.IS_NOTIFICATION, true); notifyIntent.putExtras(bundle);

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get no notification sent.  I'm calling it from the onPostExecute() method of an ASyncTask class.  I confirm that the ASyncTask is complete by a message in LogCat, but I get no notification sent to the notification bar.

Comment: Hello, I have tried it with AsyncTask it's working you can download source from here: http://webheavens.com/AsyncTaskDemo.rar

Comment: After getting sidetracked on other issues with the app, I finally got back around to trying this.  It worked!  Thank you!

Comment: @MunishKapoor how to start my app while a user clicks on the notifiction?

Comment: @MunishKapoor im getting this AppConfig cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 31):

Even though your problem is solved, I'll just post how I solved my problem that the notification was not showing, perhaps it might help other people reading the answers:

In my notification building I was missing the icon. As soon as I added something like `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)` the notification was shown.

Comment: Yes, worked for me either. First time working with notifications. Many thanks!

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot. Althought Android should just pick  default launcher icon if developer hasn't set this.

Comment: Just lost many hours trying to figure out this problem. One freaking small icon. God bless you.

Comment: I have icon but still notification was not working, I wasted so many hours but when I changed the icon to test, It started to work, so definitely it was icon issue. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

int icon = R.drawable.icon;        // icon from resources
CharSequence tickerText = "Any thing";              // ticker-text
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification   time
Context context21 = getApplicationContext();      // application   Context
CharSequence contentTitle = "Anything";  // expanded message title
CharSequence contentText = (CharSequence)  extras.get("message");     // expanded message text

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainStart.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,   notificationIntent, 0);

// the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the configurations above
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
/*  long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
notification.vibrate = vibrate;
notification.ledARGB = Color.RED;
notification.ledOffMS = 300;
notification.ledOnMS = 300;*/
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context21, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: I'm running into similar issues with this as I have before.

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, CastrRecorder.class);

That line gets marked by Eclipse and the only resolution for it is to remove the arguments.  Also, this is being called within a class that extends ASyncTask and getActivity() doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to try is to make sure your manifest contains

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Also mine seemed to ignore successive notifications with the same NOTIFICATION_ID.

Answer (score 0):

For me this kept happening and I had no idea why but the problem was that the icon I set was too large so it was giving me some random error.