# Android notifications from a BroadcastReceiver not showing

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I want to create a notification (from a BroadcastReceiver - if that makes a difference)

I don't know why, but It's just not showing up!

```
private void showNotification(Context context, String text) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029477/android-notification-not-working) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045722/notification-not-showing))

Comment: Show your whole **BroadcastReceiver** Class and the Class calling it.

Comment: Add Log.d(TAG, "message"); lines to be sure you actually reach this code  (the log messages will show up in Logcat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all answers, but I got it solved unexpectedly.
I don't know which point really solved it, but I tried this:
 1. Clean
 2. Rebuild
 3. Close Android studio
 4. Reboot
 5. Restart android studio

Answer (score 2):

Create a notification from a BroadcastReceiver - that makes the difference!
You should rewrite this string in your code:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I should have said this earlier: The BroadcastReceiver is in a Service Class, so that doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

The issues can be the following:

-1: you add the method showNotification, in a position where it's not called by the broadcast receiver.

-2: you are not registering the broadcast receiver

-3: replace this

```
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

with

```
mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

If the point 3 is not working, please, attach your whole broadcast receiver code, and where you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to -> File -> Invalid caches -> Invalidate and restart
```

The action done the job